# Filtering keyword from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering

I have two tables

Employees

```
id    employee_name  JobTitle     
---------------------------
1     John            CEO 
2     Ely             MANAGER    
3     Marcus          MANAGER    
4     Steve           CEO 
5     Fritz           ASSISTANT   
6     Orly            ANALYST
7     Carlo           ANALYST      
7     Lee             MANAGER
```

JobTitle Filter

```
filter_id     JobTitle_keyword     
---------------------------
1               CEO 
2               MANAGER
```

Is it posible to use JobTitle_keyword as the filtering keyword?
so if I run the query... the result would be like this.

```
id    employee_name  JobTitle     
---------------------------
1     John            CEO 
2     Ely             MANAGER    
3     Marcus          MANAGER    
4     Steve           CEO      
7     Lee             MANAGER
```

Comment: `SELECT a.*
FROM Employees a 
  INNER JOIN JobTitleFilter b
   ON a.JobTitle = b.JobTitle_Keyword`

Comment: sounds good.. i thought only unique id can be used in inner join

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the tables:-

```
SELECT emp.* 
FROM   Employees emp 
INNER  JOIN JobTitleFilter Job 
ON     emp.JobTitle = Job.JobTitle_Keyword
```

OR

```
Select emp.id,emp.employee_name,emp.JobTitle 
FROM Employees as emp,JobTitle as Job 
Where emp.JobTitle= Job.JobTitle_Keyword
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c7e7/4)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this in MySQL by using [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   Employees t1 
JOIN   JobTitleFilter t2 
ON     t1.jobtitle = t2.jobtitle_keyword
```

Check it working in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/059621/1).

Comment: +1 For SQL Fiddle. BTW, your query seems correct, don't know why its downvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
SELECT id,employee_name,JobTitle 
FROM Employees e 
INNER JOIN JobTitleFilter j ON e.JobTitle = j.JobTitle_Keyword
```

or you can also try this one..

```
SELECT id,employee_name,JobTitle 
FROM Employees e 
where e.JobTitle in (Select JobTitle_Keyword from JobTitleFilter)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c7e7/7)